# process RDD based on condition in SPARK scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am extracting a column of a csv file that might contain empty value. So, I need to convert those empty value to 0 first, before calling toInt?

```
val field= sc.textFile("test.txt").map(_.split(",")(8))
```

how would i go about accomplishing this?

sample data is as follow:

```
3070811,1963,1096,,"US","CA",,1,
3022811,1963,1096,,"US","CA",,1,56
3033811,1963,1096,,"US","CA",,1,23
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Do you have few lines of sample data?

Comment: just added a sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just make the toInt transformation 'safe', like so:

```
def safeToInt(s:String) = Try(s.toInt).getOrElse(0)
val field= sc.textFile("test.txt").map(entry => safeToInt(entry.split(",",-1)(8)))
```

Comment: @aaronman if there're less than 8 columns, it will throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

Need to pass -1 to split so it includes the empty colums.

```
val field= sc.textFile("test.txt").map{
    val x = _.split(",",-1)(8)
    if (x.isEmpty) 0 else x.toInt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also filter out the lines so that the 0 values don't change your statistics

```
val field= sc.textFile("test.txt").map{
  val x = _.split(",",-1)(8)
}.filter{!_.isEmpty}.map{_.toInt}
```

This will change the size of your field RDD which may or may not be what you want